# Indent Comments with rest of YAML when using indent

Tags: yaml, ruamel.yaml

When specifying an indent for a YAML document using `ruaml.yaml.YAML.indent`, comments are not included in the items being indented. These should be indented the same as the sequences/mappings they are associated with.

I believe this may be a bug with either `ruamel.yaml.emitter.Emitter.write_comment`, or a similar emitter method,  only writing the comment based on the column, and not factoring in the indentation level.

From what I've read in other bug reports, I understand *which* sequence/mapping may still be an open question in the library (which is very valid given the YAML spec states they [shouldn't be associated with any node](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2767100)), but I think a flag could be used to explicitly support it.

**Input**

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

text = """\
---
- a:
    b:
      # indent me
      - item1
      - item2
    # indent me
    c:
      d: 'scalar1'
# indent me
- e:
    f: 'scalar2'
"""
yaml = YAML()
yaml.explicit_start = True
yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
data = yaml.load(text)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

**Output**

```
---
  - a:
      b:
      # indent me
        - item1
        - item2
    # indent me
      c:
        d: scalar1
# indent me
  - e:
      f: scalar2
```

**Expected**

```
---
  - a:
      b:
        # indent me
        - item1
        - item2
      # indent me
      c:
        d: scalar1
  # indent me
  - e:
      f: scalar2
```

**Environment**

Using ruamel.yaml (==0.15.35):

- ruamel.yaml-0.15.35-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
- ruamel.yaml-0.15.35-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl

Tested on:

- python 2.7.12
- python 3.5.2

OS:

- Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Comment: What is the question here? I can understand your expectations, but they are contrary to what `ruamel.yaml` actually does (which is logical in its own way, if you know how comments are handled).

Comment: What methods do I need to override in order to comments indented with their surrounding elements?

Comment: I am not sure how you would be able to achieve that by just overriding some methods. You seem to associate the comment with the following line, whereas in ruamel.yaml they are normally associated with the preceding node. So during `dump` the comment is streamed out at a moment where you don't have information on the following node available. You would need some cache for (multi-line) comments that only outputs the comment when the following node is about to get written, and also make sure that gets flushed at the end of a document. This falls outside of the intended scope for round-tripping.